# Error GetCurrentCallstack when creating a new game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertices

Hey fellow problem solvers. I'm kinda unsure why an error is arrising.

the error is :

`"made 0x00007ff71b1c69cd (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack 0x00007ff71b1cd589 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack 0x00007ff71c150943 (Unity) GetStacktrace"`

script :
[image]
[image]

I'm expecting an identifyer and a vertices2D array with the points of the line stored in it so it may be used in another class.

Man, I tried a Class I tried have a List<List> linesPoints = new List<List>(); in the tapLine class.

Comment: Please add code to the question as text. You can't search or compile an image.

Comment: well there it is -> `UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("made");` in `line.vertices2DSet`

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing the error yourself in the `vertices2DSet` method. If you want to simply log something to the debug window, instead of using `UnityEngine.Debug.LogError`, you should be using `UnityEngine.Debug.Log`. I hope this answers your question.